# Laravel 5.5 load only the data for the currently logged in user

Tags: laravel-5.5

Hi I am new to laravel but I would like to load all the bookings for the currently logged in user.

I have tried doing this

```
   //check if user is logged in
     if ($user = Auth::user()) {  
       //get only the bookings for the currently logged in user
        $allProducts =Booking::where('client', Auth::user()->name)->where('name', $name)->first();
        //store the bookings in a products variable
        $products = json_decode(json_encode($allProducts));
      //Loop through the products:
        foreach ($products as $key => $val) {
            //get the name of the service by matching it's id in the service model to the service column in the products
            $service_name = Service::where(['id' => $val->service])->first();
      //get the charge amount of the service by matching it's id in the Charge model to the charge column in the products
            $service_fee = Charge::where(['id' => $val->charge])->first();
          //get the status of the service by matching it's id in the status model to the status column in the products
            $service_status = Status::where(['id' => $val->status])->first();
            $products[$key]->service_name = $service_name->name;
            $products[$key]->service_fee = $service_fee->total;
            $products[$key]->service_status = $service_status->name;
        }
        return view('client.booking.view_bookings')->with(compact('products'));
    }
    return view('/login');
}
```

But that is giving me an error: Undefined variable: name  on the line

```
       $allProducts =Booking::where('client', Auth::user()->name)->where('name', $name)->first();
```

What could I be doing wrong? and how can I solve it to dsplay only the required data

Comment: Where is `$name` variable being defined?

Comment: $name is not defined. what should `->where('name', $name)` accomplish? and off topic, but why do you json_decode(json_encode) something?

Comment: @MarkusDresch it should enable me get only the bookings for the current user
prevoiusly this is what I had ```$allProducts = Booking::get();``` and it was giving me the bookings for all the users who have submitted in the db

Comment: it seems like $name does not exist though. i don't know your code, but my guess is that `$allProducts =Booking::where('client', Auth::user()->name)->first();` should be enough.

Comment: @MarkusDresch I have edited the code to add comments about what I am doing. the code that you have provided seams to be returning an empty dataset

Comment: alright, but the error you are getting is still because you are using the variable $name which does not exist. check what `Auth::user()->name` returns and if it corresponds to your 'client' field. does 'client' hold the user name? without knowing your db schema it's a little hard to guess, but probably you want to compare the 'name' field to `Auth::user()->name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to understand what you are doing without success but from your explanations in the comments, I think I know what you want to do.

Since you said that this code works well for you except that it gives you the results of all the data in the database irrespective of the logged in user

```
    $allProducts = Booking::get();
```

it is because that creates a query that selects all the data in the database.

Whatv you need is to add a where clause to your statement. to do that simply add this to the above line of code

```
    where('client', Auth::user()->name)
```

it will return only the data that that contains the client column equal to the name of the currently logged in user.

Therefore the entire line of code becomes;

```
    $allProducts = Booking::get()->where('client', Auth::user()->name);
```

Alternatively you could use filters